# Measures $\mu$ such that $\mu(a+A)\leq c\ \mu(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu[a,b]<+\infty$, for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R})=+\infty$. The set $a+A$ denotes the translation set of $A$ by a, i.e. $a+A=\{a+x, \text{with }x\in A \}$.

Consider the following hypotheses on the measure $\mu$:

**(H0)** For all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ measurable set

$$\mu(a+A)=\mu(A).$$

**(H1)** $\exists c>0$ such that for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ measurable set

$$\mu(a+A)\leq c\ \mu(A).$$

Consider also the weaker hypothesis:

**(H2)** For all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists c_a>0$ such that for all $A$ measurable set

$$\mu(a+A)\leq c_a\ \mu(A).$$

We know that if $\mu$ satisfies **(H0)**, then $\mu$ is nothing but the Lebesgue measure multiplied by a constant. What can we say about **(H1)** and **(H2)** ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\beta>0$ and $c \geq 1$. For any measurable function $f(x)$ that satisfies $1 \leq f(x) \leq c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the measure $\mu(A) = \int_{x\in A} \beta f(x)dx$ satisfies H1.

Below it is shown that this example structure captures every measure $\mu(A)$ that satisfies H1 together with the properties $\mu([0,1])<\infty$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R})>0$.

---

Let $L(A)$ be the usual Lebesgue measure.  Let $\mu(A)$ be any measure on the same $\sigma$-algebra that satisfies $\mu([0,1])<\infty$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R})>0$. Suppose $\mu(A)$ satisfies H1 with respect to a particular number $c\geq 1$.  Define
$\beta = \inf_{a<b} \left[\frac{\mu([a,b])}{L([a,b])}\right]$, where the infimum is taken over all closed finite intervals $[a,b]$. 
You can prove that:

(1) $0 < \beta < \infty$.

(2) For any interval $[a,b]$ one has $\beta L([a,b])  \leq \mu([a,b]) \leq c\beta L([a,b])$.

(3) By properties of inner and outer Lebesgue measure, property (2) implies $\beta L(A) \leq \mu(A) \leq c\beta L(A)$ for all Lebesgue measurable sets $A$.

(4) Property (3) implies $\mu(A)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and so (by Radon-Nikodym) there is a measurable function $g(x)$ such that $\mu(A) = \int_{x\in A} g(x)dx$ for all measurable sets $A$.  Define $f(x) = g(x)/\beta$.

(5) You can show that $1 \leq f(x) \leq c$ almost everywhere (so just define it to be 1 at points where this is violated).  Then $\mu(A)$ has the form $\mu(A) = \int_{x\in A} \beta f(x)dx$ for a measurable function $f(x)$ that satisfies $1 \leq f(x)\leq c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I added steps (3)-(5) today, which show that the original example structure $\mu(A) = \int_{x\in A} \beta f(x)dx$ captures all measures that satisfy H1.

Comment: Well, I haven't gotten any feedback from the asker (the OP), though the answer seems to work out with a nice necessary and sufficient condition. I laid out my answer like a problem set with clear steps.  Let me know if you agree and were able to do the steps.  Some are more challenging than others, for example, proving $\beta<\infty$ is an immediate application of $\mu([0,1])<\infty$, while proving $\beta>0$ is a more interesting consequence of $\mu(\mathbb{R})>0$.